# MLP - what did author have in mind?

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I am currently going through [Machine learning and pattern recognition](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Machine-Learning-Algorithmic-Perspective-Recognition/dp/1466583282) and I have following dilemma:

A algorithm for MLP is presented in that way
[image: MLP Backwards phase]

and corresponding python code to equation 4.9 (which is of interest to me) is written that way

```
deltah = self.hidden*self.beta*(1.0-self.hidden)*(np.dot(deltao,np.transpose(self.weights2)))
```

where `self.beta` is a constant (not shown in algorithm), `self.hidden` is hidden layer neurons' output values, `deltao` is error of output layer and `self.weights2` are weights of output layer neurons.

My question is, **why author is multiplying deltao matrix by weights2 matrix and why weights2 matrix is tranposed?** Why (and how) is it equivalent to 4.9 equation?

I know that it is required get matrices to right dimensions to make multiplication possible but why does it make sense from algorithm point of view? Why can't i somehow multiply weights2 by deltao just like it is stated in equation 4.9?

Full python code is here:

```
# Code from Chapter 4 of Machine Learning: An Algorithmic Perspective (2nd Edition)
# by Stephen Marsland (http://stephenmonika.net)

# You are free to use, change, or redistribute the code in any way you wish for
# non-commercial purposes, but please maintain the name of the original author.
# This code comes with no warranty of any kind.

# Stephen Marsland, 2008, 2014

import numpy as np

class mlp:
""" A Multi-Layer Perceptron"""

def __init__(self,inputs,targets,nhidden,beta=1,momentum=0.9,outtype='logistic'):
    """ Constructor """
    # Set up network size
    self.nin = np.shape(inputs)[1]
    self.nout = np.shape(targets)[1]
    self.ndata = np.shape(inputs)[0]
    self.nhidden = nhidden

    self.beta = beta
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.outtype = outtype

    # Initialise network
    self.weights1 = (np.random.rand(self.nin+1,self.nhidden)-0.5)*2/np.sqrt(self.nin)
    self.weights2 = (np.random.rand(self.nhidden+1,self.nout)-0.5)*2/np.sqrt(self.nhidden)

def earlystopping(self,inputs,targets,valid,validtargets,eta,niterations=100):

    valid = np.concatenate((valid,-np.ones((np.shape(valid)[0],1))),axis=1)

    old_val_error1 = 100002
    old_val_error2 = 100001
    new_val_error = 100000

    count = 0
    while (((old_val_error1 - new_val_error) > 0.001) or ((old_val_error2 - old_val_error1)>0.001)):
        count+=1
        print count
        self.mlptrain(inputs,targets,eta,niterations)
        old_val_error2 = old_val_error1
        old_val_error1 = new_val_error
        validout = self.mlpfwd(valid)
        new_val_error = 0.5*np.sum((validtargets-validout)**2)

    print "Stopped", new_val_error,old_val_error1, old_val_error2
    return new_val_error

def mlptrain(self,inputs,targets,eta,niterations):
    """ Train the thing """    
    # Add the inputs that match the bias node
    inputs = np.concatenate((inputs,-np.ones((self.ndata,1))),axis=1)
    change = range(self.ndata)

    updatew1 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights1)))
    updatew2 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights2)))

    for n in range(niterations):

        self.outputs = self.mlpfwd(inputs)

        error = 0.5*np.sum((self.outputs-targets)**2)
        if (np.mod(n,100)==0):
            print "Iteration: ",n, " Error: ",error    

        # Different types of output neurons
        if self.outtype == 'linear':
            deltao = (self.outputs-targets)/self.ndata
        elif self.outtype == 'logistic':
            deltao = self.beta*(self.outputs-targets)*self.outputs*(1.0-self.outputs)
        elif self.outtype == 'softmax':
            deltao = (self.outputs-targets)*(self.outputs*(-self.outputs)+self.outputs)/self.ndata 
        else:
            print "error"

        deltah = self.hidden*self.beta*(1.0-self.hidden)*(np.dot(deltao,np.transpose(self.weights2)))

        updatew1 = eta*(np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),deltah[:,:-1])) + self.momentum*updatew1
        updatew2 = eta*(np.dot(np.transpose(self.hidden),deltao)) + self.momentum*updatew2
        self.weights1 -= updatew1
        self.weights2 -= updatew2

        # Randomise order of inputs (not necessary for matrix-based calculation)
        #np.random.shuffle(change)
        #inputs = inputs[change,:]
        #targets = targets[change,:]

def mlpfwd(self,inputs):
    """ Run the network forward """

    self.hidden = np.dot(inputs,self.weights1);
    self.hidden = 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-self.beta*self.hidden))
    self.hidden = np.concatenate((self.hidden,-np.ones((np.shape(inputs)[0],1))),axis=1)

    outputs = np.dot(self.hidden,self.weights2);

    # Different types of output neurons
    if self.outtype == 'linear':
        return outputs
    elif self.outtype == 'logistic':
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-self.beta*outputs))
    elif self.outtype == 'softmax':
        normalisers = np.sum(np.exp(outputs),axis=1)*np.ones((1,np.shape(outputs)[0]))
        return np.transpose(np.transpose(np.exp(outputs))/normalisers)
    else:
        print "error"

def confmat(self,inputs,targets):
    """Confusion matrix"""

    # Add the inputs that match the bias node
    inputs = np.concatenate((inputs,-np.ones((np.shape(inputs)[0],1))),axis=1)
    outputs = self.mlpfwd(inputs)

    nclasses = np.shape(targets)[1]

    if nclasses==1:
        nclasses = 2
        outputs = np.where(outputs>0.5,1,0)
    else:
        # 1-of-N encoding
        outputs = np.argmax(outputs,1)
        targets = np.argmax(targets,1)

    cm = np.zeros((nclasses,nclasses))
    for i in range(nclasses):
        for j in range(nclasses):
            cm[i,j] = np.sum(np.where(outputs==i,1,0)*np.where(targets==j,1,0))

    print "Confusion matrix is:"
    print cm
    print "Percentage Correct: ",np.trace(cm)/np.sum(cm)*100
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344607/is-there-a-way-to-turn-this-summation-into-a-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In formula $4.9$:
 $$\delta_h(\zeta) = \bar{g}(h_\zeta)\sum_{k=1}^N w_\zeta \delta_o(k),\text{ where }\bar{g}=g(h_\zeta)(1-g(h_\zeta)) ,$$ 
we have a $\zeta$-th neuron in a hidden layer which is connected to $N$ output neurons with weights $w_\zeta$. $\delta_o(k)$ is the error on the output neuron $k$, $w_\zeta$ is a vector of weights and it has length $N$.
So $$\sum_{k=1}^N w_\zeta \delta_o(k)= w_{\zeta1}*\delta_o(1)+w_{\zeta2}*\delta_o(2)...+w_{\zeta N}*\delta_o(N) $$

Each $\delta_o(k)$ is a vector of some length $O$, depending on the shape of the output.
$$\sum_{k=1}^N w_\zeta \delta_o(k)=w_{\zeta1}  \begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(1)\\\delta_{o2}(1)\\ ...\\\delta_{oO}(1) \end{pmatrix}+w_{\zeta2}  \begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(2)\\\delta_{o2}(2)\\ ...\\\delta_{oO}(2) \end{pmatrix} +...+w_{\zeta N}  \begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(N)\\\delta_{o2}(N)\\ ...\\\delta_{oO}(N) \end{pmatrix}  $$

This is a vector matrix multiplication (note the tranposition) :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}w_{\zeta1}&w_{\zeta2}&... w_{\zeta N}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(1)&\delta_{o2}(1)&...&\delta_{oO}(1)\\
\delta_{o1}(2)&\delta_{o2}(2)&...&\delta_{oO}(2)\\
...\\
\delta_{o1}(N)&\delta_{o2}(N)&...&\delta_{oO}(N)\\\end{pmatrix} $$

There are $M$ neurons in the hidden layer (plus a bias neuron)
$$
   \begin{pmatrix}
    w_{11}  & w_{12} & ... &w_{1N}  \\
    w_{21} & w_{22} & ... &w_{2N}  \\
    ...  \\
    w_{M+1,1} & w_{M+1,2} &... & w_{M+1,N} \\
    \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(1)&\delta_{o2}(1)&...&\delta_{oO}(1)\\
\delta_{o1}(2)&\delta_{o2}(2)&...&\delta_{oO}(2)\\
...\\
\delta_{o1}(N)&\delta_{o2}(N)&...&\delta_{oO}(N)\\\end{pmatrix} $$

Thus we have $(M+1 \times N) \cdot (N\times O)=(M+1)\times O$ resulting matrix.

Or we could represent it as a matrix vector multiplication:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(1)&\delta_{o1}(2)&...&\delta_{o1}(N)\\
\delta_{o2}(1)&\delta_{o2}(2)&...&\delta_{o2}(N)\\
...\\
\delta_{oO}(1)&\delta_{oO}(2)&...&\delta_{oO}(N)\\\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}w_{\zeta1}&w_{\zeta2}&... w_{\zeta N}  \end{pmatrix}^T= $$
$$
=\begin{pmatrix}\delta_{o1}(1)&\delta_{o2}(2)&...&\delta_{o1}(N)\\
\delta_{o2}(1)&\delta_{o2}(2)&...&\delta_{o2}(N)\\
...\\
\delta_{oO}(1)&\delta_{oO}(2)&...&\delta_{oO}(N)\\\end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
    w_{11}  & w_{12} & ... &w_{1N}  \\
    w_{21} & w_{22} & ... &w_{2N}  \\
    ...  \\
    w_{M+1,1} & w_{M+1,2} &... & w_{M+1,N} \\
    \end{pmatrix}^T
$$
getting $(O \times N) \cdot (N \times M+1) = O \times (M+1)$ matrix.

Comment: thank you a lot! i would click also top green arrow (bell?) but i have not enough points :P